# retrieve all files in subfolders in sharepoint document library using REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a folder in a document library and that contains subfolders and each subfolder contains files.
I want to retrieve all the files in these subfolders using REST. I know how to get the files in each folder but is there any way to get all these files in one REST call... Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the below endpoint to retrieve all files in a library:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$expand=File&$select=File&$filter=FSObjType eq 0
```